# How to fix 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError' error when building an Android app in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, gradle, groovy, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to build my Android application in Android Studio, but I'm encountering the following error:

```
Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7
```

I have done some research, and it seems that this error is related to the initialization of the org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7 class. I have tried various solutions, such as updating the Groovy version, and cleaning the Gradle cache, but the issue persists.

This is my Android Studio version:

```
Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-222.4459.24.2221.10121639, built on May 12, 2023


Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-9586694 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
```

This is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "es.mobisoft.glopdroidcheff"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode = 262
        versionName "2.6.2"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
repositories {
    maven { url "https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-snapshots/" }
}
dependencies {
    api fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    implementation group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '15.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    implementation group: 'org.nanohttpd', name: 'nanohttpd', version: '2.3.1'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.2.0'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.1'
    implementation 'org.fusesource.mqtt-client:mqtt-client:1.12'
    implementation 'com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:4.9.3'


}
```

Also this is my Java version:

```
openjdk version "20.0.1" 2023-04-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 20.0.1+9-29)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0.1+9-29, mixed mode, sharing)
```

This my Gradle version:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.4.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-04-26 08:14:42 UTC
Revision:     261d171646b36a6a28d5a19a69676cd098a4c19d

Kotlin:       1.3.21
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          20.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 20.0.1+9-29)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

And this my Groovy version:

```
Groovy Version: 4.0.12 JVM: 20.0.1 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Windows 10
```

I know that there are many posts indicating that this problem can be solved by updating the Gradle version of the project, but this app runs on slightly old tablets and for that reason I can't perform such an update.

Also a coworker, with the same version of gradle and java does not suffer from this error.

My coworker use this Android Studio Version : Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1

Comment: What is a "slightly old tablet" for you? A tablet running Android 5 or older? Please tell us the running Android version. Note that usually the gradle version has no direct effect on which devices can run the app.

Comment: Note: You should not use such an old Gradle version with Java 20. Better only use Java 8, otherwise you will run into problems with java 20.